# multiple responses Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express

I wrote the following signup function.
It works fine with Postman but when I've added the code between "//send the cookie with the token" and "// end", I got this error message : "(node:11748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client".
From what I saw here in stackoverflow, this error occurs because of multilple res. but I can't find how to rearrange the code so that I avoid this error.

```
exports.signup = async(req, res) => {
    const { firstName, familyName, email, password, role } = req.body;
    console.log("image", req.file);
    try {

        
        const user = await User.findOne({ attributes: ['email'], where: { email: email } });

        if (user) {
            fs.unlinkSync(req.file.path);
            return res.status(409).send('This email already exists!');
        } else {
            const hashPass = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
            const userObject = {
                firstName: firstName,
                familyName: familyName,
                email: email,
                password: hashPass,
                role: role,
                photoUrl: req.file ? `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${req.file.filename}` : null,
            };
            console.log("photo", userObject.photoUrl);
            console.log("userObject", userObject);
            const createdUser = await User.create(userObject);

            const newToken = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id },
                process.env.COOKIE_KEY, { expiresIn: "24h" }
            );
            const newCookie = { token: newToken, userId: createdUser.id };
            const cryptedToken = cryptojs.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(newCookie), process.env.COOKIE_KEY).toString();
            res.cookie('snToken', cryptedToken, {
                httpOnly: true,
                maxAge: 86400000 // 24h
            });
            res.status(200).send({ message: 'The user is successfully connected!', data: createdUser, cryptedToken: cryptedToken });

        }
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).send({ error: 'An error has occured while trying to sign up!' });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to "multiple request". In a successful case (also on error),  you wrote status more than once.

for example in a successful case:
first you returned 201 after creating the user (which returned a response to the client)
res.status(201).send({message: `User ${req.userObject.firstName} ${req.userObject.familyName} was registred`                            }, createdUser);

and then

and here you tried to send another response at the end of the request

```
res.status(200).send({ message: 'The user is successfully connected!', data: user, cryptedToken: cryptedToken });
```

and you got the right error Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client, since it already returned 201 after Creation.

try to do something like:

```
try {
    const hashPass = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    const userObject = {    firstName: firstName,
                        familyName: familyName,
                        email: email,
                        password: hashPass,
                        role: role,
                        photoUrl: req.file ? `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${req.file.filename}` : null,
                    };
                    console.log("photo", userObject.photoUrl);
                    console.log("userObject", userObject);
                    const createdUser = await User.create(userObject);

            //send the cookie with the token
            const newToken = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id },
                process.env.COOKIE_KEY, { expiresIn: "24h" }
            );
            const newCookie = { token: newToken, userId: user.id };
            const cryptedToken = cryptojs.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(newCookie), process.env.COOKIE_KEY).toString();
            res.cookie('snToken', cryptedToken, {
                httpOnly: true,
                maxAge: 86400000 // 24h
            });
            res.status(200).send({ message: 'The user is successfully connected!', data: user, cryptedToken: cryptedToken });
}
 catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).send({ error: 'An error has occured while trying to sign up!' });
 }
```

Comment: I commented the res.staus(201) and the catch error but still have the same error message. Is there a rule for that because I thought we should always write a catch statement after then and always send a response to the front ?

Comment: in that case you might have return an error and not 201. 
at one of the        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            res.status(500).send({ 'error': error });
                        });
                })
                .catch(error => res.status(500).json({ error }));

Comment: I updated the code according to your answer. I got the user in the DB but got this error message in Postman "error": "An error has occured while trying to sign up!" !! it's weird because it looks like the programm didn't enter the try bloc which is wrong because I got the user in the DB!!

Comment: and without the cookie